# Sum expression not displaying sum if there's 1 data row in sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry if title was confusing.

I have multiple sheets, my code below will go through each sheet, calculate duration/cost & then input remaining values. It works great, however there's one issue.

Issue: If there's only 1 row of data under header, it will not display total duration & cost where it inserts Total duration & cost.

Exact Issue Example:

```
Start Time  Duration    Calling Name    Dialed Number    Cost 
6/2/2016 8:58   0:01:15 BLANK_F333       1303900000      $0.12 
Total Duration:                               Total Cost:
```

Here's exact example out if there's multiple rows of data.

```
Start Time  Duration    Calling Name    Dialed Number    Cost 
6/1/2016 15:07  0:30:55 BLANK_I380  6052340000   $3.72 
6/3/2016 12:26  0:05:40 BLANK_I380  1605230000   $0.72 
6/6/2016 13:49  0:00:08 BLANK_I380  1605380000   $0.12 
6/6/2016 13:50  0:00:08 BLANK_I380  1605380000   $0.12 
6/6/2016 13:51  0:01:15 BLANK_I380  1605320000   $0.12 
6/16/2016 8:29  0:01:42 BLANK_I380  1703290000   $5.04 
Total Duration: 0:39:48                      Total Cost:     $9.84
```

I can't figure out how to output single row data sheets.

**Code**

```
Sub FormatEntry()
Dim TotalCost As Double
Dim TotalTime As Double
Dim LastRow As Long


For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next     'Will continue if an error results
    With ws
        .Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "_-[$$-40B]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-40B]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-40B]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "
        .Range("E2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
    WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("E2:E" & .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row))
    .Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
    Format(WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("B2:B" & .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row)), "hh:mm:ss")
            .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Font.Bold = True
    .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Value = "Total Duration:"
    .Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Font.Bold = True
    .Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Value = "Total Cost:"
    .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row = LastRow

End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `End(xlDown)` and when you use it against `B2` and `E2`

Because there's only 1 row, the `End(xlDown)` method will go to last row on the spreadsheet. *Look there and you will see the formula :)*

Use this instead:

```
.Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
    WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("E2:E" & .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row))
.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
    Format(WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("B2:B" & .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row)), "hh:mm:ss")
```

Alternately, if you know you will **always** have *at least* one row of data you can change the 2 row reference in your original code to 1.

```
.Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
    WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("E2:E" & .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row))
.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
    Format(WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("B2:B" & .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row)), "hh:mm:ss")
```

As a side note, this line makes no real sense:

```
.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row = LastRow
```

Comment: I tried that snippet out. Total duration worked great, however cost still had the same issue.

Comment: @CeFu - look down column E. make sure there is no other text in the columns. Go to the last filled row you can see in column E, then press `Ctrl + <down arrow>`. What happens? Also, see my edit for another solution.

Comment: I did, it was 120k rows down. That was so odd! Thanks!

Comment: @CeFu - sometimes that happens with system generated reports, if this is one, which it looks like

Comment: The initial generated report contains over 30k records. My first, separate script eliminated toll free & local numbers. I use KuTools to easily split the data into separate sheets, and then apply this script to total duration, code and last remaining formatting.